# Allow clicking in a certain box

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and Pygame 1.9.6. So I'm creating a Chessboard with moving pieces and everything. I've done all that, but now I'm doing UI things to make it smooth.

When ever I click on the screen there is a certain parameter in which I want it to click which is the entire board, for moving pieces that is.
Here is what the board and screen look like: [image]

So everything in the green box is where the error is popping up. Everything to the right of the red line works fine, no errors or nothing. Same with the chessboard. The board is (512, 512). The screen is (600, 700).
I've tried rendering the board as it's on square so when it's inside the board your allowed to click, but that didn't work. So I've also tried this: `if p.mouse.get_pos() <= (511, 511):` as a parameter. With that it only allows everything past x = 511 to not click which is the entire red line. I'm only having issues with the x-value.

My code for the main file:

```
import pygame as p
from Chess import ChessEngine3

p.init()
WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 600
DIMENSION = 8  # dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE = 512 // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15  # for animations later on
screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
IMAGES = {}

# Background Image
bg_image = p.transform.scale(p.image.load('bg.jpg'), (700, 700))

# Icon and Title
p.display.set_caption("Chess")
icon = p.image.load('images/wQ.png')
p.display.set_icon(icon)

'''
Initializes a global dictionary of image. This will be called exactly once in the main. 
'''


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 
'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
# Note we can access an image by saying "IMAGES['wp']'


'''
The main driver for our code. This will handle user input and updating the graphics. 
'''


def main():
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))
    gs = ChessEngine3.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False  # Flag variable for when a move is made
    animate = False  # Flag variable for when we should animate a move
    loadImages()  # only do this once, before the while loop
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()  # no square is selected, keep track of the last click on the user (tuple: (row, col))
    playerClicks = []  # keep track of the player Clicks (two tuples: [(6, 4), (4, 4)]
    gameOver = False
    while running:
        keys = p.key.get_pressed()
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            # mouse handler
            if e.type == p.MOUSEMOTION:
                x, y = p.mouse.get_pos()
                print(x, y)
            if p.mouse.get_pos() <= (511, 511):
                if e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if not gameOver:
                        location = p.mouse.get_pos()  # (x, y) location of the mouse
                        col = location[0] // SQ_SIZE
                        row = location[1] // SQ_SIZE
                        if sqSelected == (row, col):  # the user clicked the same square twice
                            sqSelected = ()  # deselect
                            playerClicks = []  # clear player clicks
                        else:
                            sqSelected = (row, col)
                            playerClicks.append(sqSelected)  # append for both first and second clicks\
                        if len(playerClicks) == 2:  # after 2nd click
                            move = ChessEngine3.Move(playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                            print(move.getChessNotation())
                            for i in range(len(validMoves)):
                                if move == validMoves[i]:
                                    gs.makeMove(validMoves[i], p.event)
                                    moveMade = True
                                    animate = True
                                    sqSelected = ()  # reset your clicks
                                    playerClicks = []
                            if not moveMade:
                                playerClicks = [sqSelected]

            # key handler
            if e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_r:  # reset the board when 'r' is pressed
                    running = False
                    main()
                if e.key == p.K_x:  # exits the game
                    running = False
            if not gameOver:
                if keys[p.K_LEFT]:  # undo when 'left' is pressed
                    gs.undoMove()
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                    moveMade = True
                    animate = False

        if moveMade:
            if animate:
                animateMove(gs.moveLog[-1], screen, gs.board, clock)
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
            moveMade = False
            animate = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
        if gs.checkmate:
            gameOver = True
            if gs.whiteToMove:
                drawText(screen, 'Black wins by checkmate')
            else:
                drawText(screen, 'White wins by checkmate')
        elif gs.stalemate:
            gameOver = True
            drawText(screen, 'Stalemate')
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


'''
Highlight square selected and moves for piece selected
'''


def highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    if sqSelected != ():
        r, c = sqSelected
        if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whiteToMove else 'b'):  # sqSelected is a piece that can be moved
            # highlight selected square
            s = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            s.set_alpha(100)  # transparency value -> 0 transparent; 255 opague
            s.fill(p.Color('lightblue'))
            screen.blit(s, (c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE))
            # highlight moves from that square
            s.fill(p.Color('lightgreen'))
            for move in validMoves:
                if move.startRow == r and move.startCol == c:
                    screen.blit(s, (move.endCol * SQ_SIZE, move.endRow * SQ_SIZE))


'''
For highlighting last move
'''


def lastMovehighlight(move, screen, gs, board, sqSelected):
    pass


'''
Responsible for all the graphics within a current game state.
'''


def drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    drawBoard(screen)  # draw squares on the board
    highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)  # draw pieces on top of these squares


'''
Draw the squares on the board. the top left square is always light.
'''


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r + c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


'''
Draw the pieces on the board using the current GameState.board
'''


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":  # not empty square
                 screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


'''
Animating Moves
'''


def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    global colors
    dR = move.endRow - move.startRow
    dC = move.endCol - move.startCol
    framesPerSquare = 4  # frames to move one square
    frameCount = (abs(dR) + abs(dC)) * framesPerSquare
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        r, c = (move.startRow + dR * frame / frameCount, move.startCol + dC * frame / frameCount)
        drawBoard(screen)
        drawPieces(screen, board)
        # erase the piece moved from its ending square
        color = colors[(move.endRow + move.endCol) % 2]
        endSquare = p.Rect(move.endCol * SQ_SIZE, move.endRow * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
        p.draw.rect(screen, color, endSquare)
        # draw captured piece onto rectangle
        if move.pieceCaptured != '--':
            screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceCaptured], endSquare)
        # draw moving piece
        screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceMoved], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

My error:

```
File "C:/Users/Student/PycharmProjects/Chess/Chess/ChessMain.py", line 133, in highlightSquares
if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whiteToMove else 'b'):  # sqSelected is a piece that can be moved
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I figured it out. I did this:

```
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            x, y = p.mouse.get_pos()
            # mouse handler
            if x <= 511 and y <= 511:
                if e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if not gameOver:
                        location = p.mouse.get_pos()  # (x, y) location of the mouse
                        col = location[0] // SQ_SIZE
                        row = location[1] // SQ_SIZE
                        if sqSelected == (row, col):  # the user clicked the same square twice
                        sqSelected = ()  # deselect
                        playerClicks = []
```

I also had to add a global for x and y. So I basically didn't have the `x, y = p.mouse.get_pos()` in the line that acting for it. I just did a simple x and y if statement and I was good, because I set the x and y = mouse position.

If you need anymore information or anything else let me know. I always appreciate the advice and help.

Comment: can you show more of your code?

Comment: Also show the error you are receiving.